# MVC3 application and javascripts issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have the following problem:

A ASP.NET MVC3 application, and in _Layout.cshtml, in header section, I have referenced several javascript scripts, as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/app.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/listEnveloppe.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In app.js I have defined App object as follows:

```
var App = {
init: function () {
    if (window.console == undefined) {
        window.console = {
            log: function () {
                var str = '';
                for (var i in arguments[0]) {
                    str += i + ':\t' + arguments[0][i] + '\n';
                }
                alert(str);
            }
        };
    }
/* ....*/
}
```

Then App object is referenced in listEnveloppe.js as below

```
App.listEnveloppe = new Function;
```

The problem is, this code works on FF and Chrome, but not in IE8

Does anyone knows what can be wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a lack of parenthesis in the `Function` constructor?

```
App.listEnveloppe = new Function(); // <----- missing () ?
```

---

As that wasn't the case, try declaring (and referring to) `App` as a property of `window`. And do it in an agnostic way relative to the order of declaration of the scripts:

```
// In app.js:
var appInstance = window.App || {};
appInstance.init = function () {
};

// In listEnveloppe.js:
var appInstance = window.App || {};
appInstance.listEnveloppe = new Function();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I cannot do this because the object App is further used in a lot of javascript files, and many places, and many of those files are not even under my control. Any other idea? Strange why it works ok in FF and Chrome (I cannot test in IE9)

Answer (score 1):

You have some unclosed parenthesis. Try fixing your javascript:

```
var App = {
    init: function () {
        if (window.console == undefined) {
            window.console = {
                log: function () {
                    var str = '';
                    for (var i in arguments[0]) {
                        str += i + ':\t' + arguments[0][i] + '\n';
                    }
                    alert(str);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    /* ....*/
};
```

Comment: I verified and the paranthesis are ok in app.js file. In the sample code provided I just copied a small part of app.js file